# Missing 1 required positional argument - issue

Tags: python, django

May be it's stupid question, but I'm begginer in django. I have a problem with error:

> *"PartyNumView() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'"*

**views.py**:

```
from description.models import Part
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404

def PartyNumView(request, pk, page_number = 1):
    all_parties = Part.objects.all()
    current_page = Paginator(all_parties, 10)
    try:
        context = current_page.page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        context = current_page.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        context = current_page.page(current_page.num_pages)
    onePart = get_object_or_404(Part, pk = pk)
    return render_to_response('part_list.html', {'PartyNum': context, 'onePart': onePart})
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^parties/(\d+)/$', PartyNumView),
    url(r'^parties', PartyNumView),
    url(r'parties/(?P<pk>[\d]+)$', PartyNumView, name='onePart'),
    url(r'^main/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='main.html')),       #static html
    url(r'^measures/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='IcDesc.html')),       #static html

]
```

And a little bit of **part_list.html:**

```
  {% for object in PartyNum %}

<tr>
  <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
  <td><a href="{% url 'onePart' pk = object.pk %}"> {{ object.Party_number }}</a></td>
  <td>{{ object.Film }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.Thick }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.Critical_temperature }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.R_s }}</td>

 {% endfor %}
```

In Models.py I have a class Part(models.Model)

Help me please find a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url `url(r'^parties', PartyNumView),` does not parse an argument `pk`, but it still calls the function `PartyNumView`.

You would have to use a different view function for that specific url, or use a default value:

```
def PartyNumView(request, pk=None, page_number = 1):
```

---

I suggest you read the [python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to maybe adjust your code to the standard praxis. For example, function names are usually all lowercase and separated by underscores; your `PartyNumView` could be renamed to `party_num_view` for example.

Using this style helps other python programmers to understand your code and provide better answers.

Answer (score 2):

You have two urls patterns for `PartyNumView`;

```
url(r'^parties', PartyNumView),
url(r'parties/(?P<pk>[\d]+)$', PartyNumView, name='onePart'),
```

Just delete the first, and everything will be ok, and add the `^` before the second

```
url(r'^parties/(?P<pk>[\d]+)$', PartyNumView, name='onePart'),
```

Or In case the view serves 2 different urls, don't delete your first `url`, add the `^` in the second url, then add a default argument for the `pk` in the view, like `None`

```
PartyNumView(request, pk=None, page_number = 1):
    all_parties = Part.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your url_patterns `url(r'^parties', PartyNumView),`
When this url your view not recive the pk argument it raise the exception